# Как открыть файл из директории assets

Tags: java, android

Хочу передать файл sound.mp3 на сервер. Есть метод из библиотеки, который принимает на вход аргумент класса File.
Пробую так:

```
File soundFile = new File("//android_asset/sound.mp3");
bool isExists = soundFile.exists();
```

Не работает - переменная `isExists = false`.

Comment: а путь `"file:///android_asset/filename.ext"`  не работает?

Comment: @pavlofff у меня нет, компилирую на 26 API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402757/3212712) напрямую сделать это невозможно, т.к. файлы в ассетах не хранятся как файлы.

Вам надо делать иначе:

1. Получить `InputStream` из файла в ассетах [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14515590/3212712):

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("test.mp3");
```

2. Записать этот поток в новый файл в файловой системе (вот метод, принимающий объект типа файл (в нём укажите путь к файлу и пишущий в него то, что в `InputStream`)) [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21730182/3212712):

```
public static void writeBytesToFile(InputStream is, File file) throws IOException{
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {   
        byte[] data = new byte[2048];
        int nbread = 0;
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        while((nbread=is.read(data))>-1){
            fos.write(data,0,nbread);               
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Exception",ex);
    }
    finally{
        if (fos!=null){
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему именно 2048 - длина массива байт?

Comment: @Flippy, хз. Я просто скопипастил код с `en-SO`)

Comment: мм, ясно :D ну да, я тоже так делаю))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо)

Comment: @Tim, если ответ вам помог, то вы можете отметить его "верным", нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа)